# Как функцией SUM вернуть накапливающуюся сумму с обнулением по условию?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, оконные-функции

Пытаюсь сделать запрос с функцией `SUM`, возвращающий накапливающуюся сумму с обнулением по условию. Суммы должна быть более 15, после чего она обнуляется.

Например:

```
A | 3 | 3 
B | 7 | 10 
C | 6 | 16  --<<< 
D | 5 | 5 
E | 9 | 14
F | 3 | 17  --<<<
G | 8 | 8
```

Сортировка по первому столбцу, а обнуление, где показано маркером: `--<<<`.

Как это можно сделать?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Conditional SUM on Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52936012) от участника [@Fábio Almeida](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4102241/f%c3%a1bio-almeida)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/52936012

Comment: Упомянаемый в ответах рекурсивный SQL, это рещение в самом первом ответе по ссылке выше, если кому интересно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Достичь желаемого результата можно гораздо проще, чем рекурсивным CTE. Начиная с версии 12c введена клауза `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`, которая хорошо подходит для решения проблемы [Bin Fitting](https://stewashton.wordpress.com/2014/06/06/bin-fitting-problems-with-sql/):

```
SELECT a, b, rolling_sum, bin_num
FROM t
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
    ORDER BY a
    MEASURES SUM(b) rolling_sum, MATCH_NUMBER() AS bin_num
    ALL ROWS PER MATCH
    AFTER MATCH SKIP PAST LAST ROW
    PATTERN (A+)
    DEFINE A AS SUM(b) < 15 + A.b);
```

Результат:

```
A B  ROLLING_SUM  BIN_NUM
- - ------------ --------
A 3            3        1
B 7           10        1
C 6           16        1
D 5            5        2
E 9           14        2
F 3           17        2
G 8            8        3
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3882195077d2ba9bf946f2cbf639728a)

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53994970) от участника [@Lukasz Szozda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5070879/lukasz-szozda)</sub>

Answer (score 4):

Как альтернатива рекурсивному SQL - использовать клаузу `MODEL`.
Лично считаю, что это немного проще для чтения, чем рекурсивный SQL, хотя и сложнее для написания, потому что большинству, как и мне, приходится подглядывать в синтаксис.

```
with sorted (a, sort, b, running_sum_max_15) as ( 
    select a, row_number() over (order by a), b, 0 
    from t)
select a, b, running_sum_max_15
from sorted
model 
    dimension by (sort)
    measures (a, b, running_sum_max_15)
    rules update ( 
        running_sum_max_15[1] = b[1],
        running_sum_max_15[sort>1] = 
            case when running_sum_max_15[CV(sort)-1] < 15 
                 then running_sum_max_15[CV(sort)-1] 
                 else 0 end + b[CV(sort)]
    );
```

Результат:

```
A B RUNNING_SUM_MAX_15
- - ------------------
A 3                  3
B 7                 10
C 6                 16
D 5                  5
E 9                 14
F 3                 17
G 8                  8
```

---

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d47af113fdef7cd3472a59a7ad6903b4)

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52936568) от участника [@Matthew McPeak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5174436/matthew-mcpeak)</sub>